# Flink Windows Boundaries, Watermark, Event Timestamp & Processing Time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, watermark, stream-processing

### Problem Definition & Establishing Concepts

Let’s say we have a **TumblingEventTimeWindow** with **size 5 minutes**. And we have events containing *2 basic pieces* of information:

- number
- event timestamp

In this example, we kick off our **Flink** topology at **12:00 PM worker machines’ wall clock time** (of course workers can have out of sync clocks but that’s out of the scope of this question). This topology contains **one processing operator** whose responsibility is to **sum up** the values of events belonging to each window and a KAFKA Sink which is irrelevant with regard to this question.

- This window has a [BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness) with allowed latency of **one minute**.
- **Watermark**: To my understanding, watermark in Flink and Spark Structured Stream is defined as (**max-event-timestamp-seen-so-far - allowed-lateness**). Any event whose event timestamp is **less than or equal** to this watermark will be discarded and ignored in result computations.

### Part 1 (Determining Boundaries Of The Window)

#### Happy (Real-Time) Path

In this scenario several events arrive at the **Flink Operator** with different event timestamps spanning `12:01 - 12:09`. Also, the event timestamps are relatively aligned with our **processing time** (shown in the X axis below). Since we're dealing with **EVENT_TIME** characteristic, whether or not an even belongs to a particular event should be determined via its **event timestamp**.

[image]

#### Old Data Rushing In

In that flow I have **assumed** the **boundaries** of the two **tumbling windows** are `12:00 -- 12:05` and `12:05 -- 12:10` just because we have kicked off the execution of the topology at **12:00**. If that assumption is correct (I hope not), then what happens in case of a back-filling situation in which several **old** events coming in with **much older** event timestamps and we have kicked off the topology at **12:00** again? (old enough that our lateness allowance does not cover them). Something like the following:

[image]

1. If it goes like that, then our events won't be captured in **any window** of course, so again, I'm hoping that's not the behavior :)
2. The other option would be to determine **windows' boundaries** via the event timestamp of the arriving events. If that's the case, how would that work? The **smallest event timestamp** noticed becomes the beginning of the first window and from there based on the size (in this case **5 minutes**), the consequent boundaries are determined? Cause that approach will have flaws and loopholes too. Can you please explain how does this work and how the boundaries of windows are determined?

#### Backfilling Events Rushing In

The answer to the previous question will address this as well, but I think it would be helpful to explicitly mention it here. Let's say I have this **TumblingEventTimeWindow** of **size 5 minutes**. Then at **12:00** I kick off a backfilling job which rushes in many events to the Flink operator whose timestamps cover the range `10:02 - 10:59`; but since this is a backfilling job, the **whole execution** takes about **3 minutes** to finish.

Will the job allocate **12 separate** windows and populate them correctly based on the events' event timestamps? What would be the boundaries of those **12 windows**? And will I end up with **12 output events** each of which having the **summed up** value of each allocated window?

### Part 2 (Unit/Integration Testing Of Such Stateful Operators)

I also have some concerns regarding automated testing of such logic and operators. Best way to manipulate **processing time**, trigger certain behaviors in such a way that shape desired windows' boundaries for testing purposes. Specially since the stuff that I've read so far on leveraging `Test Harnesses` seem a bit confusing and can cause some cluttered code potentially which is not that easy to read:

- [Unit Test Stateful Operators](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/testing.html#unit-testing-stateful-or-timely-udfs--custom-operators)
- [Lateness Testing of Window in Flink](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/operators/windowing/WindowOperatorTest.java#L1392-L1456)

### References

Most of what I've learned in this area and the source of some of my confusion can be found in the following places:

- [Timestmap Extractors & Watermark Emitters](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness)
- [Event Time Processing & Watermarking](http://vishnuviswanath.com/flink_eventtime.html)
- [Handling Late Data & Watermarking in Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking)

  - The **images** in that section of Spark doc were super helpful and educative. But at the same time the way windows' boundaries are aligned with those **processing times** and **not** event timestamps, caused some confusion for me.
  - Also, in that visualization, it seems like the **watermark** is computed once every **5 minutes** since that's the sliding specification of the window. Is that the determining factor for how often the **watermark** should be computed? How does this work in **Flink** with regard to different windows (e.g. `Tumbling`, `Sliding`, `Session` and more)?!

HUGE thanks in advance for your help and if you know about any better references with regard to these concepts and their internals working, please let me know.

### UPDATES AFTER @snntrable Answer Below

> If you run a Job with event time semantics, the processing time at the window operators is completely irrelevant

That is correct and I understand that part. Once you're dealing with `EVENT_TIME` characteristics, you're pretty much divorced from **processing time** in your semantics/logic. The reason I brought up the **processing time** was my confusion with regard to the following key question which still is a mystery to me:

How does the **windows' boundaries** are computed?!

Also, thanks a lot for clarifying the distinction between `out-of-orderness` and `lateness`. The code I was dealing with totally threw me off by having a misnomer (the constructor argument to a class inheriting from `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` was named `maxLatency`) :/

With that in mind, let me see if I can get this correct with regard to **how watermark is computed** and **when** an event will be **discarded** (or side-outputted):

- **Out of Orderness Assigner**

  - **current-watermark =** `max-event-time-seen-so-far - max-out-of-orderness-allowed`
- **Allowed Lateness**

  - **current-watermark =** `max-event-time-seen-so-far - allowed-lateness`
- **Regular Flow**

  - **current-watermark =** `max-event-time-seen-so-far`

And in **any of these cases**, whatever event whose **event timestamp** is **less than or equal** to the `current-watermark`, will be **discarded** (side-outputted), correct?!

And this brings up a new question. When would you wanna use `out of orderness` as opposed to `lateness`? Since the **current watermark** computation (mathematically) can be identical in these cases. And what happens when you use **both** (does that even make sense)?!

#### Back To Windows' Boundaries

This is still the main mystery to me. Given all the discussion above, let'e revisit the concrete example I provided and see how the **windows' boundaries** are determined here. Let's say we have the following scenario (events are in the shape of `(value, timestamp)`):

- Operator kicked off at **12:00 PM** (that's the **processing time**)
- Events arriving at the operator in the following order

  - (1, **8:29**)
  - (5, **8:26**)
  - (3, **9:48**)
  - (7, **9:46**)
- We have a **TumblingEventTimeWindow** with size **5 minutes**

  - The window is applied to a `DataStream` with `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` which has **2 minute** `maxOutOfOrderness`
- **Also**, the window is configured with `allowedLateness` of **1 minute**

NOTE: If you cannot have both `out of orderness` and `lateness` or does **not** make sense, please **only** consider the `out of orderness` in the example above.

Finally, can you please layout the **windows** which will have some events allocated to them **and**, please specify the **boundaries** of those windows (**beginning** and **end** timestamps of the window). I'm assuming the boundaries are determined by **events' timestamps as well** but it's a bit tricky to figure them out in concrete examples like this one.

Again, HUGE thanks in advance and truly appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Original Answer

> Watermark: To my understanding, watermark in Flink and Spark Structured Stream is defined as (max-event-timestamp-seen-so-far - allowed-lateness). Any event whose event timestamp is less than or equal to this watermark will be discarded and ignored in result computations.

This is not correct and might be the source of the confusion. Out-of-Orderness and Lateness are different concepts in Flink. With the `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` the watermark is `max-event-timestamp-seen-so-far - max-out-of-orderness`. More about Allowed Lateness in the Flink Documentation [1].

If you run a Job with event time semantics, the processing time at the window operators is completely irrelevant:

- events will be assigned to their windows based on their event time timestamp
- time windows will be triggered once the watermarks reaches their maximum timestamp (`window end time -1`).
- events with a timestamp older than `current watermark - allowed lateness` are discarded or sent to the late data side output [1]

This means, if you start a job at 12:00pm (processing time) and start ingesting data from the past, the watermark will also be (even further) in the past. So, the configured `allowedLateness` is irrelevant, because the data is not late with respect to even time.

On the other hand, if you first ingest some data from 12:00pm and afterwards data from 10:00pm, the watermark will have already advanced to ~12:00pm before you ingest the old data. In this case the data from 10:00pm will be "late". If it is later than the configured `allowedLateness` (default=0) it is discarded (default) or sent to a side output (if configured) [1].

#### Follow Up Answers

The timeline for an event time window is the following:

1. first element with timestamp within the a window arrives -> state for this window (& key) is created
2. `watermark >= window_endtime - 1` arrives -> window is fired (results are emitted), but state is not discarded
3. `watermark >= window_endtime + allowed_latenes` arrives -> state is discarded

Between 2. and 3. events for this window are late, but within the allowed lateness. The events are added to the existing state and - per default - the window is fired on each record emitting a refined result.

After 3. events for this window will be discarded (or sent to the late output sink).

So, yes, it makes sense to configure both. The out of orderness determines, when the window is fired for the first time, while the allowed lateness determines how long the state is kept around to potentially update the results.

Regarding the boundaries: tumbling event time windows have a fixed length, are aligned across keys and start at the unix epoch. Empty windows, don't exist. For your example this means:

- (1, 8:29) is added to window (8:25 - 8:29:59:999)
- (5, 8:26) is added to window (8:25 - 8:29:59:999)
- (3, 9:48) is added to window (9:45 - 9:49:59:999)
- (8:25 - 8:29:59:999) is fired because the watermark has advanced to 9:48-0:02=9:46, which is larger than the last timestamp of the window. The window state is also discarded, because the watermark has advanced to 9:46, which is also larger than the end time of the window + the allowed lateness (1 minute)
- (7, 9:46) is added to window is added to window (9:45 - 9:49:59:999)

Hope this helps.

Konstantin

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#allowed-lateness

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's certainly helpful. It brings up a couple of questions along with the main mystery of **windows' boundaries** which is still confusing to me. I have updated the original question, please check out the section titled `UPDATES AFTER @snntrable Answer Below`. Thanks A LOT!

Comment: AWESOME! This is much more clear and concrete now. Something I could not find in any resource I found online :) Huge thanks again, really appreciate it. I might turn this in to a blog post and reference this conversation there.

Comment: This answer is 10 times better than flink's official documentation.

Comment: (5, 8:26) is added to window (8:25 - 8:29:59:999), I think that this case is dropped, because the watermark is 8:27 (previous eventtime is 8:29 and the out of orderness is 2 mins). so the 08:26 will be dropped. Am I right? @snntrable

Comment: Just want to echo (needlessly maybe) that this answer and https://www.ververica.com/blog/how-apache-flink-enables-new-streaming-applications-part-1 finally made things "click" for me. Which the official docs haven't managed.